# Hide/Show form based on Dropdownbox selection

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I have looked around and haven't found anything concrete.

Is there any tutorials on how to show/hide a form or textbox based on if a value is selected.

I have something like this Dropdown box with (Add, item1, item2,item3 ect..)

if add is selected show a form to add add with some attributes such as (First Name, last Name ect..) else it will just do an action with the selected item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select id="target">
    <option value="option1" selected="selected">Add</option>
    <option value="option2">Item1</option>
  </select>

<input type="text" class="textboxclass" />

<div class="someform">
//content
</div>
```

Default css display property for someform class is none eg:

```
.someform{display:none;}
```

Jquery script

```
<script>
$('#target').change(function() {
  var name = $('#target option:selected'),text(); //Item1
  var id = $('#target').val(); // option2

  if(id =="option2"){
   //your logic for this option
   //hide textbox
   $('.textboxclass').hide();
   $('.someform').show();
   }else{
   $('.textboxclass').show();
   $('.someform').hide();

}
   //other if else logic

});
</script>
```

Not tested since im on laptop without any software installed.

Comment: hey, this works great except for one bug, as soon as the page is loaded all the div's are shown. For example, if my option1 is started on page the the textboxclass and the someform are both visible, where only one should be.

Comment: add display:none in your css for all divs who you like to be hidden

Answer (score 0):

I would wire this up in the client-code. Handle the select's `onchange` event in JavaScript or jQuery and bind a handler to it. Since "**Add**" is the only one that will show the form, in your handler check for the value selected and if it's the value for "**Add**", show the form. If it's any other value, hide the form.

If you want to do this in the server code, just handle the event for the selection changed and set the visibility property of your form that way. Either way should be pretty easy.

Doing this on the client allows you to avoid coding around postbacks while removing responsibility of processing the request from the server.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do this from server side you will need to set the AutoPostBack propetry of DrowpDown list to true,

and in the SelectedIndexChanged event of DropdownList

try this,

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
     {
         entryForm.Visible = true;
         viewForm.Visible = false;
     }
     else if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
     {
         entryForm.Visible = false;
         viewForm.Visible = true;

}
```

but this is not a good aproach, i will suggest to follow the answers given above, and do it with JavaScript or JQuery